# The a tag href is not my expectant url

Tags: django

I have a project(`pyProject`), and in it have a APP(`app02`).

And in the `pyProject/urls.py`, I routed the app02:

```
from app02 import views as app02_v

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    ...
    url(r'^app02/', include("app02.urls")),
]
```

In the `app02/urls.py`:

```
import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^index/$', views.Index.as_view()),
    ...
    url(r'^userinfo/', views.userinfo),
]
```

the `app02/views.py`:

```
def userinfo(request):

    # QuerySet
    user_list = models.UserInfo.objects.all()
    print (user_list.query)
    return render(request, 'app02/userinfo.html', {'user_list':user_list})
```

And in the templates:
`templates/index.html`:

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:48px; bottom:0; left:0; width:200px;background-color:#333">
    <a class="menu" href="app02/userinfo/">用户管理</a>
    <a class="menu" href="app02/ugroup/">用户组管理</a>
</div>
```

But when I click the `<a class="menu" href="app02/userinfo/">用户管理</a>` tag, print the error:

> Not Found: /index/app02/userinfo/

Why it is not the `/app02/userinfo/`? why there is `/index` more ?
My expert is request the `/app02/userinfo/`.

[image]

Comment: try /app02/userinfo/ for path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `name` keyword argument to your `url`s like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^index/$', views.Index.as_view()), name='index',
    ...
    url(r'^userinfo/', views.userinfo), name='user_info',
]
```

And then use the Django `url` template tag to render your URL's automatically like this:

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:48px; bottom:0; left:0; width:200px;background-color:#333">
    <a class="menu" href="{% url 'user_info' %}">用户管理</a>
    <a class="menu" href="app02/ugroup/">用户组管理</a>
</div>
```

The syntax is `{% url '<view_name>' %}` where `view_name` is the `name` defined in the `url`.

Answer (score 0):

In the a tag href you should use the absolute path:

```
<a class="menu" href="/app02/userinfo/">用户管理</a>
```

If use the relative path, it will append after to your current url.